# React native: Firebase rules

Tags: firebase, react-native

I followed a tutorial to upload images with firebase and image-picker. At the end he says he has to change the firebase rules, but he doesn't say which file to put. Can someone help me?
This is the blog link and it’s at the end that he talks about it: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/upload-images-to-firebase-storage-in-react-native

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because if the blogger removes that link the question won't make any sense and will be of no help to future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firebase rules are changed in the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/)

Select your project, and you should see a menu that looks like this:

[image]

Click on which database you're using and go to rules

[image]

The example in the blog doesn't look like realtime database rules, so it's probably Cloud Firestore